# What is that ASCII Art From the Portal Credits

Tags: portal

The end credits to *Portal* include a bunch of ASCII art, but one of them is really hard to make out. The one below looks like some sort log-cake or something. I’ve tried resizing it up and down, but it did not make it any clearer.

My best guess (if I really squint and stretch my imagination) is that it is supposed to be one of GLaDOS’s spheres.

Can anyone shed some light on what it is supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: I think it's a security camera, _looking_ at you. It could also be the rocket launcher, however.

Comment: to me it looks much like Wheatly from PORTAL2

Comment: I actually spent 30 minutes with a couple of screen shots carefully transposing the characters one-by-one into notepad.  Then I discovered that it all had already been done and I should have just Googled for it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the ASCII art it's "GLADOS"

Check [this](http://www.halflife2.net/forums/showthread.php?132014-spoiler-end-credits-ascii-art&s=47f8784d3936ccaf0bdb7fa9a0323c84) page. Look at the second post, click Show and scroll down to GLADOS you'll see the same ASCII art there in reference to that name.

EDIT: In case that page goes away here it is

```
"GLADOS1" "[12.000]       #+ @      # #              M#@   "
"GLADOS2" "[12.000] .    .X  X.%##@;# #   +@#######X. @#%  "
"GLADOS3" "[12.000]   ,==.   ,######M+  -#####%M####M-    #"
"GLADOS4" "[12.000]  :H##M%:=##+ .M##M,;#####/+#######% ,M#"
"GLADOS5" "[12.000] .M########=  =@#@.=#####M=M#######=  X#"
"GLADOS6" "[12.000] :@@MMM##M.  -##M.,#######M#######. =  M"
"GLADOS7" "[12.000]             @##..###:.    .H####. @@ X,"
"GLADOS8" "[12.000]   ############: ###,/####;  /##= @#. M "
"GLADOS9" "[12.000]           ,M## ;##,@#M;/M#M  @# X#% X# "
"GLADOS10" "[12.000].%=   ######M## ##.M#:   ./#M ,M #M ,#$ "
"GLADOS11" "[12.000]##/         $## #+;#: #### ;#/ M M- @# :"
"GLADOS12" "[12.000]#+ #M@MM###M-;M #:$#-##$H# .#X @ + $#. #"
"GLADOS13" "[12.000]      ######/.: #%=# M#:MM./#.-#  @#: H#"
"GLADOS14" "[12.000]+,.=   @###: /@ %#,@  ##@X #,-#@.##% .@#"
"GLADOS15" "[12.000]#####+;/##/ @##  @#,+       /#M    . X, "
"GLADOS16" "[12.000]   ;###M#@ M###H .#M-     ,##M  ;@@; ###"
"GLADOS17" "[12.000]   .M#M##H ;####X ,@#######M/ -M###$  -H"
"GLADOS18" "[12.000]    .M###%  X####H  .@@MM@;  ;@#M@      "
"GLADOS19" "[12.000]      H#M    /@####/      ,++.  / ==-,  "
"GLADOS20" "[12.000]               ,=/:, .+X@MMH@#H  #####$="
```

Comment: That would fit with the lyrics. "Look at me..."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with badp, I think it is one of the security cameras found throughout the levels.

Answer (score -2):

Before the launch of Portal 2, that ASCII are a clue to the next game, its like the clip in the end of that credits, we can see some cores like "weathly", only be a reference to the history of the second game.

Comment: When Portal was first released, no sequel was planned and the ending cutscene did not show Chell getting recaptured. That was only added after the fact.

Answer (score -4):

it is GLaDOS as the words on the right tell you what the picture is supposed to be on the left if you look at some of the other art in Viper_Sb's answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you; that was established three years ago (a nice, definitive answer only 26 minutes after the question was posted).